# Passing ember-data model to component and getting weird result

Tags: ember.js

```
ember@2.1.0 
ember-data@2.1.0
```

I am passing a simple model to a component but getting the following object (I looks like the actual ember-data model is under the value property).  Why is model pointing to this instead of the actual model?

[image]

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('employee');
  }

})
```

**Template**

```
{{log model}} {{!-- logging here correctly displays the ember-data object --}}
{{my-component model=model}}
```

I also tried this:

```
<my-component model={{model}} /> <!-- which prints the folowing in HTML <model-editor model="<dummy@model:employee::ember395:null>"></model-editor>-->
```

**Component (my-component)**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout,

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    console.log(this.attrs.model); //Prints the Object above
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `this.get('model')` instead of `this.attrs.model` to get the behavior you expect.

However if you would like to keep using `this.attrs.model` you need to explicitly reference `this.attrs.model.value` to get `model` attribute value.

It's because `model` attribute is passed with both it's `value` and way to update it - `update` function.

The concept is similiar to `mut` helper. [You can read more about this behavior here.](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html#toc_the-code-mut-code-helper)

Comment: From ember 3.4 and above, you could also access the passed data, `model` in this case, as `this.model`. Using `this.get` is optional.